# Linq to Sql DatabaseExists

Tags: sql, linq

Lets say i have a database in c:\database.mdf
what is the difference between using context.DatabaseExists("c:\database.mdf") 
or just simply checking with File.exists("c:\database.mdf")  ?

i ask this because i get strange behavior form DatabaseExists method :
it tells me sometimes that c:\database.mdf exists but it's not there, because i
manually deleted the file from windows explorer.

what am i missing ?

Answer (score 1):

`DatabaseExists` actually tries to open a connection to the database. This means it must be a valid database.

`FileExists` only checks whether a file with that name exists, not whether it is valid.

You could create a .txt file and rename it database.mdf. `FileExists` will return true while `DatabaseExists` will return false.

Comment: ok, i understand,  but in my case, i deleted my file manually
and CreateDatabase method throws an exception which says the database name already exists.

Comment: Is it possible you just removed it from your project instead of deleting it?